# how to insert all column header names into a list from qsqltablemodel table?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, qsqltablemodel

Below is my db model example:

```
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
db.setDatabaseName('book.db')
db.open()

self.model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
self.model.setTable("card")
self.model.select()

column_names = [ ]
```

How to get all column header names into a list from qsqltablemodel table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the the API documentation (for the C++ version), the `record()` function can be used to obtain an empty record, for the purpose of extracting the field names ([reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#record)):

> It returns an empty record, having only the field names. This function can be used to retrieve the field names of a record.

From the record, we can obtain the number of fields and then query the name of each field in a list comprehension expression:

```
record = model.record()
column_names = [ record.fieldName(i) for i in range(record.count()) ]
```